# Recursively remove all adjacent duplicates. I'm getting same output for different inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, data-structures

code

```
def dup(n, s):
    s1 = ""
    list = []
    k = 0

    for i in range(0, n-1):
        if k > 0:
            if s[i] == s[i+1]:
                k = 2
            k = k-1
            continue

        if (s[i] == s[i+1]):
            k = 1
            continue

        else:
            list.append(s[i])

    if s[n-2] != s[n-1]:       
        list.append(s[n-1])

    s1 = "".join(list)

    n1 = len(s1)

    for i in range(0, n1-1):
        if s1[i] == s1[i+1]:
            dup(n1, s1)

        else:
            print(s1)        
num = int(input())
for j in range(0, num):
    s = input()
    n = len(s)
    dup(n, s)
```

I'm getting same output for different inputs.

Input:

```
quhxgrhqqaccxeprunllfieilbothbbmpsg
```

Its Correct output is:

```
quhxgrhaxeprunfieilbothmpsg
```

And Your Code's output is:
gksforgk
**

Comment: Please re-take the intro tour, especially the part about "make it easy for others to help you."  We expect a clear example -- you haven't supplied the distinctly different inputs that incorrectly give the same output.  We also expect clear, readable code to debug; your lack of meaningful variable names and your lack of any explanation to your algorithm, is likely why nobody has yet dealt with the code in your posting.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you do in your code, but if you want to do this pythonically, here is what you can do in one line:

```
from itertools import groupby

s = 'quhxgrhqqaccxeprunllfieilbothbbmpsg'

result = ''.join([k for k, g in groupby(s) if len(list(g)) == 1])
# quhxgrhaxeprunfieilbothmpsg
```

This basically groups all adjacent same elements and we instruct to not take them if we have more than one same adjacent elements.